# How to make application autorun on Mac?

Tags: macos, autorun

I want to make my application autorun, like using autorun.inf on Windows. I googled and there is one way for me to do that:
"On the Mac side there are many applications you can buy for creating a Finder window that looks a certain way but all these changes can be made within finder. You then will need to copy the DS_Store file to the CD and finder will automatically apply any changes that you have made.

Also using -hfs-openfolder will cause it to open automatically when inserted on the mac."

Can anyone tell me more clearly about that, or is there any other way?
Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you mean by “autorun”? Start each time you log in? (See context menu in the dock.) Start automatically when inserting a CD? (One of the worst ideas ever, imho.) Please don't assume people know what you mean by referring to some way of getting there on some other platform …

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean when I insert a CD, I want it automatically open a Finder window like double-clicking on a disk icon on Desktop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://jordan.broughs.net/archives/2008/03/creating-cross-platform-windows-and-mac-installer-cds), you should be able to do that with `bless`:

```
sudo bless --folder "/Volumes/discName" --openfolder "/Volumes/discName"
```

The man page confirms that, at least on 10.6.8. I don't have Lion in front of me right now.